# Return table from function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, psql

Following function works with SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE(@EVAL_TYPE VARCHAR(6))
RETURNS @EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE TABLE (   
   PROBATION_START_ATT_CODE varchar(6) NULL
) 
AS
BEGIN
IF @EVAL_TYPE='New'
    INSERT INTO @EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE (PROBATION_START_ATT_CODE)
   SELECT NEW_EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE FROM HS_HR_PEA_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES;         
   ELSE  
   INSERT INTO @EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE (PROBATION_START_ATT_CODE)
   SELECT EXIS_EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE FROM HS_HR_PEA_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES;       
RETURN;   
END;
```

I just want to convert this to Oracle equivalent query . Tried but not succeeded.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE(EVAL_TYPE VARCHAR(6))
RETURN EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE  IS TABLE    
   PROBATION_START_ATT_CODE VARCHAR(6) NULL;

AS
BEGIN
IF EVAL_TYPE='New'
    INSERT INTO EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE (PROBATION_START_ATT_CODE)
   SELECT NEW_EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE FROM HS_HR_PEA_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES;         
   ELSE  
   INSERT INTO EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE (PROBATION_START_ATT_CODE)
   SELECT EXIS_EMP_PROB_START_ATT_CODE FROM HS_HR_PEA_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES;       
RETURN;   
END;
```

> Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Any help guys..

Comment: Run `show errors` to see the real error message.

Comment: Or select * from user_errors;

Answer (score 3):

First of all, create a database-wide type:

```
create type string_tab6 is table of varchar2(6);
```

Then you would create your function like so:

```
create or replace function get_emp_prob_start_att_code(eval_type varchar2)
return string_tab6
is
  v_array string_tab6;
begin
  if eval_type = 'New' then
    select new_emp_prob_start_att_code
    bulk collect into v_array
    from hs_hr_pea_dynamic_attributes;
  else
    select exis_emp_prob_start_att_code
    bulk collect into v_array
    from hs_hr_pea_dynamic_attributes;
  end if;

  return v_array;
end get_emp_prob_start_att_code;
/
```

However, I would question why you need such a function. What are you going to use it for?

In Oracle, I'd expect to see that logic embedded directly into whichever SQL statement needs that info, which you could easily do via a case statement.

Answer (score 1):

First define row type. For existing database table you can use `%ROWTYPE`.
Then define table type.
Finally use the table type as return type of the function.

```
TYPE tr_row IS my_table%ROWTYPE;
TYPE tab_row IS TABLE OF tr_row;
FUNCTION get_row RETURN tab_row IS
  mytab tab_row;
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM my_table
    BULK COLLECT INTO mytab;
    RETURN mytab;
END;
```

Comment: That would work for a function defined in a package which is only ever called from a PL/SQL context; but as the OP seems to want a schema-level function it would need to be a schema-level (SQL) type (and you can't use `%rowtype` outside PL/SQL either).

Comment: @alexpoole I would not create a schema level function for such specialised behavior. But it is not a problem to create a schema level function, which just calls the packaged one.

Comment: No, I wouldn't create a function at all for this in Oracle; bonesist noted the same.